# How do I go to another frame when the animation ends

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation

I have a question about if a animation ends that it will like `gotoAndStop()` to another frame

```
if (bird.hitTestObject(pipe1)) {

     bird.gotoAndStop(3); //frame 3 = animation

}
```

after it ends it will need to go the Game Over frame (frame 3) and I use the `Flash Timeline` not `.as` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but you can attach ActionScript code to keyframes. Simply put, when the playhead hits that frame, that code will be executed. In Flash Professional, just click on the keyframe where your animation ends, open up the "Actions" panel and write whatever code you need to be executed when the animation ends.

Answer (score 0):

e.g. If you have a `MovieClip` placed on the stage having (say 60 frames) of animation.

Now, on the Main Timeline (i.e Stage Timeline) you want to go to keyframe no.3 but only after animation in the above `MovieClip` is finished (i.e if it's on 60th `keyframe`), then add the following line to the last `keyframe` (here 60 th) of that `MovieClip` like so,

`MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop(3);` // here `this.parent` refers to Stage Timeline

In your case (Question is not clear though) it might be,

`MovieClip(this.parent).bird.gotoAndStop(3);`

Some more examples for understanding,

`MovieClip(this.parent).score;` //Accessing `Score` from main Timeline.
`MovieClip(this.parent.parent).health;` //Nested clips

But I do not recommend this approach as It gets harder to debug and maintain as Projects get  larger. Instead use `OOP`, `MVC` like pattern and for animation use `TweenLite` for example.

Comment: do you have skype or something so i can show you what is wrong?